# jQuery, replace and animate img element

Tags: jquery, animation, replace

jQuery newbie here! I'm trying to replace an image with another, while animating it at the same time. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<img id="salt" src="images/salt.png" alt="salt"/>
<img id="pepper" src="images/pepper.jpg" alt="pepper"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#salt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#pepper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#salt").click(function(){
    $("#salt").animate({left: '300px'});
    $('#pepper').show();
    $('#salt').replaceWith($('#pepper'));

  });
});
```

The animation is working fine when 'replaceWith' is inactive; yet when when I'm trying to replace the image, salt just disappears and pepper appears at its first position. I need one of the two (really don't mind which) to perform the motion and then pepper to be shown where salt would normally be after the animation. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a callback function for the animation

```
  $("#salt" ).animate({
    left: '300px'
  }, 5000, function() {
    $('#pepper').show();
    $('#salt').replaceWith($('#pepper'));
  });
```

When the animation is finished, the function get called

Comment: And make sure you change #pepper 's css as well

Comment: The function works perfectly now, thank you so much!! I'm still having problems with the CSS part though... I changed pepper to `left: 480px;` and now, once the animation is finished, it suddenly "jumps" several pixels to the right; shouldn't it be at the same place where salt was last seen, since they have the same size etc???

Comment: You probably want to set to `left: '300px'`

Comment: Oh right, I shouldn't have added the extra 180px to it---- thanks again!!